# Get grandchildren from Person instance in simple ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have implemented inheritance in rails and get children and grandchildren from Person class.

But now I want to get the children and grandchildren from Person class using simple ruby classes without using ActiveRecord.

I have managed to get the children from a person object. Kindly guide me how can I get the grandchildren from a Person instance.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  attr_reader :ref

 def initialize(name, ref)
   @name = name
   @ref = ref
 end
end

class Parent < Person
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(names = %w(A B C))
   @children = names.map do |n|
     Person.new(n, self)
    end
  end
end


bar = Parent.new.children.first
bar.ref
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no behavior differences between a parent, child, and granchild, then this can be modeled with one class:

```
class Person

  attr_reader :children
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name, children: [])
    @name = name
    @children = children
  end

  def grandchildren
    @children.flat_map(&:children)
  end

end
```

We've added a #grandchildren method that asks each child for their children.  This example shows how it works:

```
sally = Person.new("Sally")
fred = Person.new("Fred", children: [sally])
mary = Person.new("mary", children: [fred])
p mary.children.map(&:name)         # => ["Fred"]
p mary.grandchildren.map(&:name)    # => ["Sally"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify things to the bare minimum needed by your question with `NameMagic` (gem `y_support/name_magic`, install by `gem install y_support`):

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'

class Person
  include NameMagic
  attr_accessor :children

  def initialize( children: [] )
    @children = Array( children )
  end

  def grandchildren
    children.map( &:children ).flatten.uniq
  end
end
```

Now `NameMagic` takes care of naming people for you, while you take care of defining the family tree:

```
Mary = Person.new
Fred, Joe = Person.new, Person.new
Mary.children << Fred << Joe
Sally, Sam = Person.new, Person.new
Fred.children << Sally << Sam
Jane = Person.new
Joe.children << Jane
```

And then

```
Mary.grandchildren
#=> [Sally, Sam, Jane]
```

Note that `y_support/name_magic` allows you to name objects simply by constant assignment and tells `inspect` method to show names. It also automagically handles `:name` keyword parameter of the `new` constructor:

```
Joe.children << Person.new( name: :Mike )
# now Mary has 4 grandchildren
Mary.grandchildren
#=> [Sally, Sam, Jane, Mike]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing NameMagic.  I hadn't seen that gem before.

Comment: I wrote it personally :-)

Answer (score 0):

You were both faster than me. But, sometimes children have new children:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :children

  def initialize(args={})
    @name = args[:name]
  end

  def children
    @children ||= []
  end

  def children=(children_ary)
    children << children_ary
    children.flatten!
  end

  def grandchildren
    children.flat_map(&:children)
  end

end
```

Suzie has two kids, Bobby and Harriet:

```
suzie   = Person.new(name: 'Suzie')
bobby   = Person.new(name: 'Bobby')
harriet = Person.new(name: 'Harriet')
suzie.children = [bobby, harriet]
```

But, poor Suzie has no grandchildren:

```
puts "Suzie has #{suzie.grandchildren.count} grandchildren named #{suzie.grandchildren.map(&:name)}"
=> Suzie has 0 grandchildren named []
```

But, then the little blessings come:

```
ralph   = Person.new(name: 'Ralph')
madge   = Person.new(name: 'Madge')
bea     = Person.new(name: 'Bea')

bobby.children = [ralph]
harriet.children = [madge, bea]
```

And now Suzie is a happy grandma:

```
puts "Suzie has #{suzie.grandchildren.count} grandchildren named #{suzie.grandchildren.map(&:name)}"
Suzie has 3 grandchildren named ["Ralph", "Madge", "Bea"]
```

And Bobby keeps 'em coming:

```
johnny = Person.new(name: 'Johhny')
bobby.children = [johnny]

puts "Suzie has #{suzie.grandchildren.count} grandchildren named #{suzie.grandchildren.map(&:name)}"
=> Suzie has 4 grandchildren named ["Ralph", "Johhny", "Madge", "Bea"]
```

Thanks to Wayne for flat_map!

Comment: Sorry, you guys were for sure way first and I didn't really add anything. I was just trying to have some fun.

Comment: Am having similar issues,how do we handle great grand children and so on